# Core allocation and priority of irq/18-ttyS8

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tty, serial-port

I'm developing an embedded system running RT Linux 5.4. Intel CPU with multiple cores. I need to make sure that my processes run at sufficiently high RT priority on specific cores. However, these processes do a lot of serial port reading/writing. The kernel creates a thread like `irq/18-ttyS8` to handle the serial communication. If my process has higher priority than this one serial communication is not reliable. So I need to know, to make the system reliable, which core this IRQ thread will run on and with what priority.

How does the kernel decides what priority to assign to `irq/18-ttyS8` and on which core to run it? Is it possible to thane this - priority and core?

Edit: the `isolcpus=1,2,3`. There are 4 cores on this CPU. However, `irq/18-ttyS8` runs on core 2.